# How to merge 2 Dataview vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

**i want to merge 2 dataview the first have and Code,Name,credit, 0 on debit and the second have
Code,Name,0 on credit,  debit .
i want to merge the line of the first with the line of the second to get a dataview that have 1 line :
code,name,Credit,debit**

Sub Facture_old_Getdata()

```
    Dim sRs, sRs1 As String

    sRs = " select CodeClt,client , Sum(MontantTTc) As Credit , Cast('' As Double ) As Debit " _
         & "from LV_Fact_CLient " _
         & "where 1=1 and Codeclt ='" & TxtCodeClient.Text & "'" _
         & "group by Codeclt,Client"


    Rsdata = New DataView

    Rsdata = c_DataSql.fGet_Data_ViewAccess(sRs)



    sRs1 = "select Codeclt,Client , Cast('' As Double) As Credit , SUM(Montant) As Debit " _
        & " from Gestionreg " _
        & "where 1=1 and Codeclt ='" & TxtCodeClient.Text & "'" _
        & "group by Codeclt,Client"

    Rsdata1 = New DataView

    Rsdata1 = c_DataSql.fGet_Data_ViewAccess(sRs1)


    Rsdata1.Table.Merge(Rsdata.Table, False, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem has less to do with vb.net than with SQL.
In this case UNION is your friend. You can find more here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Link only answer is discouraged on SO. Please elaborate .